# Python3: csv circular import

Tags: python, csv

This is my code:

```
import csv

with open('cars.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['ID'], row['CIP'], row['NAME'])
```

I'm getting this message:

```
$ python3 csv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/salut/load-testing/csv.py", line 1, in <module>
    import csv
  File "/home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/salut/load-testing/csv.py", line 4, in <module>
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'csv' has no attribute 'DictReader' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Rename your file to something different, not `csv.py`. You shadow the `csv` module from standard library

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @buran in comments, you are overwriting the built-in `csv` model. Indeed, a python file is a module itself. More on this can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

Just a little experiment to wrap your head around it. Try to modify your code in `csv.py` as follows:

```
import csv

print(csv) # tell me something about such a `csv`
```

now if you run such a file, you get something like this:

```
<module 'csv' from '/home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/salut/load-testing/csv.py'>
<module 'csv' from '/home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/salut/load-testing/csv.py'>
```

This happens because the `print` statement is run twice: the first time when you `import csv`, the second time when the module is executed by the interpreter. Note that your `csv` module is actually your file now (look at the path)! This is not want you want.

Then try to rename `csv.py` into `my_csv.py`, as suggested by @buran and run this renamed file. This time you get:

```
<module 'csv' from '/<built-in-module-path>/csv.py'>
```

Two things to note here:

1. the `print` statement is run just once. This happens because this time `import csv` actually imports the built-in module that doesn't have any print statements. What you get in the standard output is the `print(csv)` in your `my_csv.py`.
2. note that this time the path of `csv` points to the built-in Python module.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your script csv.py

It cannot have the same name as the module